# Change Glassfish Servlet Encoding/Charset

Tags: servlets, character-encoding, glassfish

I'm sending a Serializable object to Servlet on Glassfish 4.1 server, the object has String fields with Arabic chars, when I try to log the Arabic values I got (?????)

I've read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770380/jsp-glassfish-how-to-setup-utf-8-encoding-correctly) and [This](https://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Configuration/URI_Encoding) and many other posts but nothing solved the problem, **I've tried the same codes on Tomcat 8 Server and it works fine**

What should I do with Glassfish server or my Servlet to read UTF-8 chars correctly?

### Sending the Serializable  object:

```
        url = new URL(ServerInfo.STORABLE_RECEIVER_URL);            
        http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-object;  charset=utf-8");
        http.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setDoInput(true);          
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(http.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(t);
```

### web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Set Response Character Encoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.abdullahcodes.serv.MyFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Set Response Character Encoding</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/TradableReceiver</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<locale-encoding-mapping-list>
    <locale-encoding-mapping>
        <locale>ar</locale>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </locale-encoding-mapping>
</locale-encoding-mapping-list>
```

### MyFilter

Copied from Omri Spector answer on [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279504/unable-to-change-charset-from-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8-in-glassfish-3-1)

### glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <jsp-config>
    </jsp-config>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

### Servlet test received Serializable object:

```
        log("sys: "+System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
        log("def: "+Charset.defaultCharset());
        log("size: "+b.totalRowsCount()+", "+b.totalColumnsCount());
        log("test arabic: هلوووووووووويااا");
        System.out.println("test sysout: اوووه خطبها نصيب");
        while (b.hasNext()) {
            Position p = new Position();
            p.setEn(b.next());
            p.setAr(b.next());
            log("p: "+p.toString());                
        }
```

### Console output on Glassfish:

```
log():net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: sys: Cp1252
log():net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: def: windows-1252
log():net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: size: 4, 2
log():net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: test arabic: ????????????????
Info: test sysout: ????? ????? ????
log():net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: p: id: 0, en: fatima, ar: abod
log():net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: p: id: 0, en: maryam, ar: nora
log():net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: p: id: 0, en: ????, ar: ????
log():net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: p: id: 0, en: ????, ar: ????
```

### Console output on Tomcat:

```
log INFO: net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: sys: UTF-8
log INFO: net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: def: UTF-8
log INFO: net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: size: 4, 2
log INFO: net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: test arabic: هلوووووووووويااا
test sysout: اوووه خطبها نصيب
log INFO: net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: p: id: 0, en: fatima, ar: abod
log INFO: net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: p: id: 0, en: maryam, ar: nora
log INFO: net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: p: id: 0, en: احمد, ar: صالح
log INFO: net.abdullahcodes.serv.TradableReceiver: p: id: 0, en: حسين, ar:
```

Comment: Is Tomcat and Glassfish running on the same machine and OS?

Comment: Yes, both on my machine (localhost)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the command line property:

```
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

when starting Glassfish.

If you're starting from your IDE then you need to add this setting to the launch configuration.

If Glassfish is being started as a service then you need to set an environment variable:

```
 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```